# Parcel - How do I add type definitions?

Tags: typescript, parcel

I am trying to import a .png file in my Typescript project but the module cannot be found. I am using Parcel as my compiler, and I want to add type definitions. How do I do that for Parcel specifically, because I couldn't find any info about it?

Comment: parcel calls the typescript compiler which in turn is configured with the tsconfig.json file. You can edit the paths to type definition files there. I'm not sure what this has to do with a .png file, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a globals.d.ts to the project with `declare module "*.png";`
in it.

Comment: This is not really a solution, just a hack to switch off type checking. Are you sure there are no proper definitions available. Such as these for example : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/pngjs

Comment: If I install the package nothing happens even tho it has the png type. Should I add something in my tsconfig?>

Comment: Posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59311324/typescript-typescript-does-not-appear-to-be-installing-new-types

Answer (score 1):

Parcel relies on the typescript compiler, which is configured by tsconfig.json. The relevant documentation can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Among other things, the config allows you to specify source files to be compiled. The following would be a valid config, all `.ts` and `.d.ts` files in the src path would be processed by the compiler:

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

In addition to that, many node modules ship with typescript definitions. They are [handled by this rule](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

If the module that is supposed to handle the .png file can't be found this is probably because it doesn't come with typescript definitions out of the box.
There is a [repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) which collects type definitions for many node modules. Maybe you find the definitions there. [Maybe these](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/pngjs)?

[There is also an example](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-i-get-them) on how to install the definitions.

It is also possible that no type definitions exist for that module yet. In that case you'll have to come up with your own. This isn't necessarily as bad as it sounds. Often you can create a minimal declaration file that only covers the handful of methods you actually use. Here are the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) on that, take a look at the examples.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention: This doesn't sound like it's related to Parcel. Under the hood, Parcel is just calling the typescript compiler itself. Cutting out the middle man can make the error messages easier to understand. You might want to try calling the typescript compiler directly and configuring it until all errors and warnings are handled. This will be more direct and hide the added complexity of Parcel. If the typescript compiler is happy, Parcel should be working as well.

Comment: How would I call the typescript compiler directly to configure it? I'm new to this so what you just said is rocket science to me.